# Shell script file for compiling and producing output of C file

Tags: c, unix, gcc, g++

I wrote this .sh file to compile any c source file, so that when I run it, it asks for a filename and gcc compiles it and then, runs the executable a.out.

But this doesn't work properly when error is present in .c files. It also shows that a.out is not present. I don't want this error message ( a.out is not present ) but just want to print only the error message generated for the .c files..

Here's the script..

```
echo `clear`
echo enter file name
read FILE
gcc $FILE
./a.out
echo -e '\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain compilation and execution commands:

```
echo `clear`
echo enter file name
read FILE
gcc $FILE && ./a.out
echo -e '\n'
```

Here, if gcc will fail, the shell will drop the ./a.out command.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable abort-on-error in shell scripts, life will be a lot easier:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu # makes your program exit on error or unbound variable
# ...your code here...
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing builtin rules as an alternative to your script you might want to use `make` as an alternative to a handcrafted script. To compile `file.c` and run the generated executable  all you need to do is:

```
make file && ./file
```

If you don't know it, I strongly suggest you take a look at the `make` utility as it will ease your work a lot. Managing anything more than a one file project can get really nasty without it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also protect the file name with double quotes :

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
echo -n "Enter file name: "
read FILE
gcc -Wall -W "$FILE" && ./a.out
echo
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of those -Wall -W...I forgot to use them for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I there hope this is what you were looking it only requires this command:

> ./compile executableName myCProgram.c -lm

you can place more C files ahead of each others and add more libraries at the end of the line and executableName does not require the .exe

```
#!/bin/bash
args="$@"
quant=$#

#Copies in case you need the -lm(math library) params
biblio=${args#*-}
#grabs all params except the first one which should be the name of the executable
firstCommand=${*:2:${#args}}
#Remove the "-lm -lc" from firstCommand
firstCommand=${firstCommand%%-*}

printf "\nEXECUTING: gcc -W -Wall -c $firstCommand\n"

#Creates the object file ".o"
gcc -W -Wall -c $firstCommand

#Convert the files names from example.c to example.o
args=${args//.c/.o}
printf "\nEXECUTING: gcc -o $args\n\n"

#Creates the executable
gcc -o $args

printf "\n**Now execute comand: ./$1  **\n\n"
```